# Android Gradle download library not complete

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I have an Android project with Gradle version 6.6.1, Android Gradle plugin 4.2.0-alpha10 and Kotlin 1.4.0.
Then I noticed that some functions and classes were missing in the kotlin standard library.
This is the Kotlin library:
[image: Missing functions and classes]

This is the kotlin-stdlib implementation:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

Does anyone known this issue and knowns how to resolve this?

**EDIT**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/" }

        maven { url "https://maven.google.com/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-alpha10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha'
        //classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com/" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

=====

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-allopen'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    //id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}

allOpen {
    annotation 'XXXXXX'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += [
                        "room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                        "room.incremental": "true",
                        "room.expandProjection": "true"
                ]
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled false
    }
    signingConfigs {
        prod {
            keyAlias 'SM'
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
            storeFile file('XXXXXXX')
            storePassword KEY_PASSWORD
        }
        dev {
            keyAlias 'SM'
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
            storeFile file('XXXXXXX')
            storePassword KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs += '-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
   flavorDimensions "version"
   productFlavors {
       prod {
           dimension "version"
           signingConfig signingConfigs.prod
       }
       dev {
           dimension "version"
           applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
           versionNameSuffix "-dev"
           signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
           proguardFile 'proguard-rules-dev.pro'
       }
   }
   variantFilter { variant ->
       def names = variant.flavors*.name

       if (names.contains("prod") && variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
           variant.ignore = true
       }
   }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':cache')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5"


    // MIKEPENZ
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:8.0.3'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer-nav:8.0.3"
    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer-iconics:8.0.3"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:itemanimators:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:5.0.3'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:5.0.3"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.9.0.0-kotlin@aar'

    implementation "com.mikepenz:fastadapter:5.2.2"
    implementation "com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions-binding:5.2.2"
    implementation "com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions-diff:5.2.2"
    implementation "com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions-scroll:5.2.2"
    implementation "com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions-ui:5.2.2"
    implementation "com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions-utils:5.2.2"
    // mikepenz

    implementation 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3@aar'

    // ANDROIDX
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    kapt "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"

    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-rxjava2:2.4.0"
    // androidx

    // GOOGLE
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02"
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    // google

    // ROOM
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.5"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.5"
    // room

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    // LIFECYCLE
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:2.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    // lifecycle

    // DAGGER
    /*
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.3'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.25.2'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.25.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.25.2'
     */

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28.3-alpha'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha'

    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0-alpha02'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'
    // dagger

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.2"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:1.10.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.1"
    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.10.0'
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.8.1"

    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
    implementation "io.noties.markwon:core:4.5.1"
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:20030805.205232'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:3.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.ongakuer.circleindicator:LoopingViewPager:2.1.4'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.4'

    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.6.1'

    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:stfalcon-imageviewer:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-vision'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-vision'
    }
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-object-detection-model:19.0.5'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'

    //debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.1'

    debugImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:3.2.0"

    releaseImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.2.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
    testImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.28.3'
    kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.19.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:2.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation  'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.28.3'
    kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3'
}
```

Comment: can you update the build.gradle.kt?

Comment: I'm not using the Gradle Kotlin DSL script.

Comment: you are using Gradle, can you publish the code of gradle file?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Mh! only one test try to clean the project, "menuBar" -> "Build" -> "Clean Project" and after try to recompile

Comment: I have already done that, even delete Android Studio and .gradle folder.

Comment: did you try to downgrade the gradle version to a stable version?

Comment: Yes, still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin plugin 1.4.0 doesn't support Android Studio 4.2. For AS 4.2 use the version 1.4.10 of the plugin.

You can try this two option to install it.

1. Trying to install it following from [android studio settings](https://kotlinlang.org/eap/install-eap-plugin.html)
2. Manually downloading from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions/staging) and installing it from disk

You can change the version directly on you Gradle file and it will work. But AS will complaint about the difference with the bundled version.